# Help Desk (by krea) won't upload attachments

Tags: ee2

I'm using Helpdesk add-on (EE 2.10.1 HD 1.2.5). I have a problem with attachments. If someone emails me attachment it works fine - it is visible in the Helpdesk panel, and in the server folder. Path and the url are set properly and destination is writable. However If I will reply, post note with the attachment it will not be write to server. I get no error but the attachment is not written. Same story with the creating ticket. I'm able to select the attachment but after saving the ticket the file is gone.

I did the clean install of the EE and the HD but the issue persist.

I'm on Mac, tested with few different browsers.

Any ideas?

Comment: I came across this too and ended up hacking the add-on to get it working.

Comment: James, I'd recommend answering the question if you found a solution. If you had to hack it, it also sounds like a bug report should be filed with Krea.

Comment: James, I will be deeply appreciated since I have no answer from the krea team.